# CloudKit user authentication with single sign-on

Tags: ios, swift, single-sign-on, icloud, cloudkit

How does one implement Sign sign-on with CloudKit in iOS8?

I understand that you can get a [string that represents your logged-in user](https://medium.com/@skreutzb/ios-onboarding-without-signup-screens-cb7a76d01d6e#.u0w6szgdp) that is unique to your app but how can I verify that string in my backend?

I understand that the Apple ID / iCloud email address is hidden for privacy reasons.

My backend is ASP.NET Web Api 2 in Azure but I could implement it in another technology if easier.

I am looking for the equivalent of Google's single sign-on on Android.

I realise that I could use the [Accounts framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/AccountsFrameworkRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011024) but from what I understand this allows the user to log-in with services like Twitter or Google. I want the user to log-in with their Apple ID as they are guaranteed to have one.

Answer (score 0):

Single sign on to what? Do you want to match a user in a 2nd app?

The only thing you get from cloudkit is an ID that is unique for that user within your app. You could use that ID to identify the user within your app.

In an other app that user will probably have an other ID. So you have to create your own mechanism to match that ID to a username. You would need to create a user and in the 2nd app you have to be able to login / connect to that user.